# Select first element of a comma-separated list

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a field column that contains values like

```
4  
12,3  
8,5,6,7
```

I'm going to write a SELECT statement, whose result would be:

```
4  
12  
8
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Did you want the first value for each row?

Comment: yes i want the first value for each row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

I'm hoping you are looking for this kind of solution.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Value NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @table VALUES('4'),('12,3'),('8,5,6,7')

select *,
IIF(CHARINDEX(',', [Value]) = 0, [Value],SUBSTRING([Value],1,(CHARINDEX(',',[Value])-1))) AS [OutPut]
from @table
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this

For SQL Server:

```
select if(charindex(',', numbers) = 0, numbers, LEFT(numbers, charindex(',', numbers) - 1))
from table;
```

For MySQL:

```
select if(instr(numbers, ',') = 0, numbers, LEFT(numbers, instr(numbers, ',') - 1))
from table;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for SQL server

```
DECLARE @CSV_Split TABLE
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    CSVData NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @CSV_Split VALUES('4'),('12,3'),('8,5,6,7')

select *,LEFT(CSVData, CHARINDEX(',', CSVData + ',') - 1)
from @CSV_Split
```

The output is something like this:

[image]